# function that return data type that can be used in SQL(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For example I was using oracle sql:

```
SELECT rpad(salary, 10 , '*')
from employees;
```

At the "10" part, I wish I can use a function to directly return the byte of the data type.
I tried

```
SELECT rpad(salary, salary, '*')
from employees;
```

and the result was scary.

is there any way to do it, or I have to create a function in plsql?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? By any chance, something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm)?

Comment: What do you mean by "return the byte of the data type"?

Comment: hi there, not thats not the result I want. 
For example i use describe employees and all the name and type will come out. The salary type is NUMBER(8,2). I dont want to use "describe" to search for the type and I want to use a way that directly return the (8,2) inside the rpad statement.

Comment: EMPLOYEE_ID             NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20) 

in above case, phone_number byte size is 20, email bytesize is 25.. I am sorry my explanation is bad.

Comment: I can imagine a function like this for simple types like NUMBER or VARCHAR2, but what do you want to get for types like FLOAT, DOUBLE, CLOB, BLOB, DATE, TIMESTAMP which don't have any "default" format and length ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill to max length of data in the column in the whole table using the below:

```
  select rpad( salary,  
      max(length(salary)) over (partition by (select null from dual)), 
       '*') 
   from  employees
```

Or to full possible size using data_length in user_tab_columns table

```
select rpad( salary,  
     (select data_length from user_tab_columns 
        where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES' and 
        column_name = 'SALARY' ), 
     '*') from  employees
```

Comment: hey dcieslak, thank you for your reply. The first one isnt the result I wanted, but the second one is the result I wanted!! Thank you!

Comment: @nicklowkc Great that I could help. If it's ok , you can mark my post as answer to close the question.