# Function the return number by using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to make a function that return the data_byte which later I can use in rpad function. Heres the previous question I have asked and I got helpful replies.
[function that return data type that can be used in SQL(oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077659/function-that-return-data-type-that-can-be-used-in-sqloracle/35077973?noredirect=1#comment57879384_35077973)

Here is the current function code I add:

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_data(tab_name in varchar2, column_name in varchar2) return number
is
  return_val NUMBER;
  str varchar2(1000) := 'select data_length from user_tab_columns where table_name = ' || ''''||tab_name||''''|| ' and column_name = ' || '''' || column_name || '''';
begin
 dbms_output.put_line(str);
  execute immediate(str);
  return(return_val);
end;
/
select get_data('EMPLOYEES', 'SALARY') from dual;
```

I keep bear in mind that function need to return type. After successfully compiled the function, I tried to select it from dual, and I got NULL value. I expected it return 22 for me but I only got null. Is that because my return type is wrong? or how should i fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that return_val is not being populated. The below code for example works:

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_data(tab_name in varchar2, column_name in varchar2) return number
is
  return_val NUMBER;
  str varchar2(1000) := 'select data_length from user_tab_columns where table_name = ' || ''''||tab_name||''''|| ' and column_name = ' || '''' || column_name || '''';
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(str);
  execute immediate(str) INTO return_val;
  return(return_val);
end;
```

Comment: Hi Chrisrs2292, may I know why "INTO" must be written after execute immediate? Is the reason same as SELECT INTO statement? I tried to find the "INTO" theory so I can understand it better but there was no result. If that doesn't bother you, could you explain the reason? Sorry if I am asking dumb questions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I encountered a new problem. When I select the column which has data type "NUMBER" it returns 22. But when i select the other data types, it returns the exact number that defined. For example, column with data type number(2,2) or number(8,2), it always return 22.

Comment: Without the "INTO", Oracle has no idea where to place the value returned from the query. Like you say, this is basically the same as "Select Into" and you can read about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm

As for why you are getting 22, this basically comes down to how numbers are stored in the database. You can read more about it here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1619552483055

If you wanted to return the "8,2" you would need the Data_Precision and Data_Scale columns from user_tab_columns

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```
execute immediate str into return_val;
return return_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic sql in this case. Simply user CURSOR or SELECT INTO clause like this:

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_data(tab_name in varchar2, column_name in varchar2) return number is
  return_val NUMBER;
  cursor c_data(cp_table Varchar2, cp_column Varchar2) is
    select data_length
      from user_tab_columns
      where table_name = cp_table and
            column_name = cp_column;
begin

  open c_data(tab_name, column_name);
  fetch c_data into return_val;
  close c_data;

  return(return_val);
end;
```

Comment: _"When you use dynamic SQl, you cant use your function in SELECT statement"_. Are you sure about this?

Comment: I was - until I have done a test :) in earlier version it was not possible because of potential side effects. Now Oracle obviously checkes side effects at runtime, so select is possible, other DML not. I will corrent my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_data(tab_name in varchar2, column_name in varchar2) return number
is
  return_val NUMBER;
begin
select data_length into return_val from user_tab_columns where table_name = tab_name and column_name = column_name
and rownum<2;
return return_val;
end;
/
```